# Rails - Creating a before filter to check if it's been 7 days, then add new item

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I'll admit I don't exactly know why a before filter is (or even if it is) the best way to handle my problem, but I've been told by a developer who knows a helluva lot more than I do about Rails programming that it is. So I'm gonna try and make it work!

So what I'm trying to do is check to see if the latest book in the database was created 7 days ago or more, and if so, create a new one.

Here's what my books controller currently looks like:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_seven_days, :only => [:create]

...

def create
    @book = Book.new(params[:book])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@book.user), notice: 'Book was successfully added to your queue.' }
        format.json { render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

...

protected
        def check_seven_days
            @user = User.find(params[:id])

            @not_queued_books = @user.books.not_queued

            @not_queued_books.each do |book|
                Book.new if book.created_at >= 7.days.ago
            end
        end


end
```

However that's not exactly working...at all. The code in the before filter is more or less pseudo-code. We'll call it that because I'm still learning how to write Ruby properly! But hopefully you can get the point of what I'm trying to do :)

And also, so you can see where this is coming from, I am using scopes in the model to check if a book has been added more than 25 seconds ago:

```
scope :queued, lambda { where('created_at > ?', 25.seconds.ago) }
  scope :not_queued, lambda { where('created_at <= ?', 25.seconds.ago) }
  scope :date_desc, order("created_at DESC")
```

Also, the view loop (in the users show view) looks like this:

```
<% @not_queued_books.date_desc.each do |book| %>
    <%= book.title %>
    <%= book.author %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Book.new is just going to instantiate a new Book object without saving and without any parameters; did you mean:

```
Book.create(params[:book])
```

?

Comment: Yes, that definitely is a start!

Comment: Do you think that needs to be inside the ```@not_queued_books``` block? Just looking for reinforcement on my solution here :)

Comment: I wouldn't place the create inside the scope, a filter is a way better place for logic like that.

Comment: It's inside a filter already though. So if I take it out of the scope, I'll have to insert it into some other type of loop to get the latest one won't I?